# Java web application context

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, websphere, war

I have a Java web application. Inside the WAR I have a folder containing configuration files for the application. I need to know the path of the folder in order to load the files at runtime.

I also need the solution to work in Tomcat and in WebSphere.

Thanks.

Comment: **I also need the solution to work in tomcat and in websphere.**. Solutions to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest placing the files under `WEB-INF/classes` and simplying loading them from the classpath, not from the filesystem. This way, the path is always the same.

You can use something like:

```
InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path");
```